# Magento 2 filter products by price from Rest API

Tags: magento2, price, layered-navigation, rest-api, search-criteria

Magento-2 we would like to filter the products from REST API

I have filtered product by price in the frontend please check the result in the below  screenshot

```
(24-MB02 price and special price we set at admin end)
```

Screenshot:-

[image]

But API Level:-

the same product 24-MB02 is missing

Api Url:- `/rest/V1/products/`

> http://10.0.0.55/ma221/rest/V1/products/?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=4&searchCriteria[filterGroups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6AJI.png)[filters][0][field]=price&searchCriteria[filterGroups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6AJI.png)[filters][0][value]=40&searchCriteria[filterGroups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6AJI.png)[filters][0][condition_type]=gteq&searchCriteria[filterGroups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XWb3.png)[filters][0][field]=price&searchCriteria[filterGroups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XWb3.png)[filters][0][value]=50&searchCriteria[filterGroups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XWb3.png)[filters][0][condition_type]=lteq

But result we are getting 4 products

[image]

output:-

[image]

Please help on this. Thanks. How to achieve this?

`/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php`

```
public function getList(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection */
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        $this->extensionAttributesJoinProcessor->process($collection);

        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->joinAttribute('status', 'catalog_product/status', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
        $collection->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');


        $this->collectionProcessor->process($searchCriteria, $collection);

        $collection->load();

        $collection->addCategoryIds();
        $searchResult = $this->searchResultsFactory->create();
        $searchResult->setSearchCriteria($searchCriteria);
        $searchResult->setItems($collection->getItems());
        $searchResult->setTotalCount($collection->getSize());

        foreach ($collection->getItems() as $product) {
            $this->cacheProduct(
                $this->getCacheKey(
                    [
                        false,
                        $product->hasData(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::STORE_ID) ? $product->getStoreId() : null
                    ]
                ),
                $product
            );
        }

        return $searchResult;
    }
```

Comment: Any updates on this.

Comment: @PushpendraSingh  i didn't get any fix, still my issue exist,  may i know whether u have any idea ?

Comment: I am facing same issue, unfortunately currently I have no Idea.

Comment: Hi @PushpendraSingh i am also trying same from my end, if u found any solution or fix please share me thanks

Comment: Any updates on this

Comment: No @shivashankarm

Answer (score 0):

This is because **product 24-MB02** price is **$59.0** (discount price is **$40.0**) - that's why it does not show in **$40-50** range.

But if you filter by **"special_price"** or whatever your discount price field name is - it will show up.

In order to include both **regular** and **discounted** products in your filter query - do logical AND & OR search like so:

```
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]:price
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]:MIN_PRICE
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]:gteq
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][field]:special_price
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][value]:MIN_PRICE
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][condition_type]:gteq
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]:price
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]:MAX_PRICE
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]:lteq
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][1][field]:special_price
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][1][value]:MAX_PRICE
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][1][condition_type]:lteq
```

Check out this link if you need more search query examples - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/performing-searches.html#logical-and-search